# Can I use a DC power supply to run a windshield wiper motor?

Tags: power-supply, power, dc

I built a 9' tall Ferris wheel out of PVC and is powered by wiper motor. It has been up and running the past two years using a 12V battery with a battery tender. My issue is I can't control it when my Christmas light show starts unless I physically walk up to it and turn it off, then back on 20 mins later. Running 3 to 4 shows a night for over a month is a lot of trips to the Ferris wheel!

If I can use a DC power supply I can control the AC going into it automatically.

I'm looking at this one: [DC power supply](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08GP8NGXG)

Comment: yes, DC is DC, no matter whether it comes from a battery or a supply. Whether that supply is a good choice - can't tell you, we don't know what the needs of your wiper motor are. Also, a lab power supply would seem to be a bit of an overkill, fixed 12 V supply are relatively abundant, and chances are you've got one lying around (or a neighbor is throwing one out).

Comment: @MarcusMüller I don't know. The folks I worked with regularly in Heerenveen pretty much seemed certain that everything they did was better than everything I did in the US. I'm sure they'd say that their DC isn't the same as mine! Probably be offended at the idea. They'd say theirs was better! ;) Otherwise, of course, I agree with your comment.

Comment: DC motor has a start current up to 12 times bigger nominal. Keep it I mind then choosing PS.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use a DC power supply to run a [DC] motor? Yes.

Is the power supply you've selected going to work? Maybe. What are the specifications of the motor?

A cursory search for generic automotive wiper motors suggests they may require 2A normally with 10A stall current. Yours may differ.

A 12V 10A fixed single-voltage supply can be found relatively inexpensively. Look for "12V 120W" or "12V 10A" power supplies. If you're going to use it outdoors, be sure to acquire one that's appropriate. Personally, I would want one with overvoltage and overcurrent protection and is made by a reputable manufacturer with specifications. For example, I might consider a [Meanwell GST160A12-R7B](https://www.meanwellusa.com/webapp/product/search.aspx?prod=GST160A).

***All of this is purely speculative. Check what your motor's requirements actually are.***